# Linux Bash - Formatting "wc - l" output with thousand separators

Tags: linux, wc

Thanks for your patience with this beginner. I've googled this seemingly easy task for hours without luck. I apologize in advance if I'm using the wrong terminology.

I'm trying to insert thousand separators into the standard output of wc -l:

```
Current Output:
1000  one.txt
2000  two.txt
1000  three.txt
4000  total

Desired Output:
1,000  one.txt
2,000  two.txt
1,000  three.txt
4,000  total
```

I'm able to use   `printf ""%'d""`   in other scenarios when I simply want the count and not the filename. But in this scenario I also need the filename.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Pipe the output to a `while read -r count filename` loop. Then you can use `printf`.

Comment: What's preventing you from using the filename? `printf %"'"'d %s\n' "$count" "$filename"`

Comment: Your `printf` won't work, the quoting is wrong.

Comment: Just pipe the data into `awk '{ $1 = sprintf("%'"'"'d", $1) }1'`

Comment: Ah sorry yes, the quotes are because I'm running this within a sas program using the x statement. Should have removed them. I'm trying what you suggested above. Thank you!

Comment: I tried this:
    wc -l one two three | awk '{ $1 = sprintf("%'"'"'d", $1) }1' >> test  

But I get this:  
    awk: syntax error near line 1
    awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: Thank you @WilliamPursell! changing to nawk made the above statement work for me (I guess because of my environment):

    wc -l one two three | nawk '{ $1 = sprintf("%'"'"'d", $1) }1' >> test

Comment: The single quote inside the awk script is terminating the quote that wraps around the script.